# 'Keyerror at /' when passing user with primary key in queryset for a listview

Tags: python, django, listview, django-queryset, django-related-manager

**models.py**

```
class Notes(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

**views.py**

```
class HomepageView(ListView):
    model = Notes
    template_name = "home.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Notes.objects.filter(Q(author=self.kwargs['pk']))
```

It points out pk has KeyError, is there any way to get rid of it
Thanks in advance...!

Comment: Can you share the relevant `path`? Is there a `<pk>` parameter in the path?

Comment: here is the path for the view
```
path('', HomepageView.as_view(), name='home'),
```

Comment: You don't say `author__pk` ?

Comment: `Notes.objects.filter(Q(author__pk=self.kwargs['pk']))` 
the error still exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `self.kwargs` contains the parameters, that are in the URL path. So in your `urls.py`, you should define shomething like:

```
# urls.py

from app.views import HomePageView

urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:pk>/', HomePageView.as_view()),
]
```

Then you can visit the page, with a valid primary key, so for example `/14` if `14` is a valid primary key for a `User`.

If you want to use the logged in user instead, you should use `self.request.user` instead:

```
# in case you want to use the logged in user

django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class HomepageView(LoginRequired, ListView):
    model = Notes
    template_name = 'home.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Notes.objects.filter(author=self.request.user)
```

> **Note**: it might be better to use [**`get_user_model`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model) to point to the user model, since if you later change the user model, altering the foreign keys will be easier.

> **Note**: You might want to consider using a [**`DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) instead of the `models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)`, since that will make the field non-editable, etc.